# Regex to match path like /^String1(anything)(String2 or String3)/

Tags: javascript, regex

For example:

```
String1: Books>Programming>
String2: Databases>
String3: Languages>
Anything: ''
```

is matched by the following regex:

```
/^Books>Programming>(Databases>|Languages>)/
```

Now, let's say Anything is not empty, e.g. "whatever1>", how should the regex change?

I tried with [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) but no luck, I may be missing something obvious.

Comment: Use a negated character class - `[^>]*`, see https://regex101.com/r/UU93P7/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you corectly you want to match path like ***Books>Programming>[anything]>(Databases> | Languages>)***. If so you can do it like this.

```
let String1 = "Books>Programming>",  
    String2 = "Databases>",
    String3 = "Languages>"

let regex = new RegExp(`${String1}(.*?)>(?:${String2}|${String3})`)
```

Benefit of this method is that you can modify variables at will and create modified regex while executing your code so it's not hard-coded.

Now if you want to test if string matches this pattern you can use:

```
regex.test("Books>Programming>whatever1>Databases>")
```

And if you want to extrat **whatever1** from this just use:

```
"Books>Programming>abc>Databases>".match(regex)[1]
```

Comment: That works, except that it matches the case where neither String2 nor String3 are present. Maybe it was not clear in the description, but at least one of the two must be there, i.e. `Books>Programming>whatever1>` must not match.

Comment: @SC1000 Have you tested code? Because it is working as you expect. :/ 
[Try](https://regex101.com/r/0o3Tdo/1) I dont see this error.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I had to test it within mongoDB and at first it didn't seem to work as desired. Accepted your answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**String.prototype.split**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to acheive that without the use of regular expressions. Like this:

```js
function getParts(str) {
  var parts = str.split(">"); // split the string by ">"
  if(!parts[parts.length - 1].length) // if the last part is empty
    parts.pop(); // remove it
  
  return parts; // return the array of the parts (ordered by default)
}

console.log(getParts("Something>Books>Another thing>Programming>"));
```

Comment: Thanks, I must stick to using regex (since this is also needed for a mongoDB query)